# can not run functions.config() locally after updating to the latest firebase tools 3.17.3 / 5.8.1

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have very simple "Node.js functions.config()" code that reads simple property value.

```
const smtpEmail = functions.config().smtp.email;
```

The code was functioning with earlier Firebase versions, however after updating to the latest firebase tools v"3.17.3" and firebase-admin "5.8.1", firebase-functions "0.8.1", I got a weird stubborn parse error with functions.config()

I ran `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json` multiple times inside the functions directory, but I still got Firebase complaining with the following error message when I try to run the functions locally.

```
!  functions: Failed to load functions source code. Ensure that you have the latest SDK by running npm i --save firebase-functions inside the functions directory.
!  functions: Error from emulator. FirebaseError: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\android-projects\firebase\functions\index.js:85:42)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at C:\Users\GIGABYTE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\GIGABYTE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:38:3)
```

This is the format of the generated ".runtimeconfig.json" file.

```
{
  "smtp": {
    "email": "myemail@domain.com",
    "password": "password"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that's failing.

Comment: Where is your `.runtimeconfig.json` located in your project folders?

Comment: it has been always located inside the "functions" directory, prior to updating the Firebase tools, things were working smoothly without any issue.

Comment: Where is your line of code that reads the config?  Inside a trigger function, or at the global scope?

Comment: the code has broken just after the update, things were running smoothly before, the parser is complaining that these values does not exists, const smtpEmail = functions.config().smtp.email;
const smtpPassword = functions.config().smtp.password;

Comment: Could you please answer my question in the last comment?  Exactly where is this line of code that was working and no longer works?  Maybe just edit your question to show the entire, minimal index.js where it is not working as you expect?

Comment: const smtpEmail = functions.config().smtp.email;  this one single line of code sir.

Comment: I'm asking you *where* in your code does this line exist?  Certainly there is not just this one line of code sitting in your index.js.  Please share as much of your code as you can.

Comment: irrelevant, it wont work even with a simple HTTP function of hello world.

Comment: It is relevant.  In my tests, I see the error you're seeing when the line is outside of a function, but I do not see it when the line is inside a function.  It would be very helpful if you showed the complete file that exhibits the behavior you're seeing. I'm constructing a bug report to send to the Firebase team, and more information is always better.

Comment: @MarcosDaSilva Apparently, there is a bug that has been introduced lately. I'm also facing the same problem after upgrading firebase-functions and firebase-tools. Check this one https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/629 and this one https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/625

Comment: @MarcosDaSilva Based on this one (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/632) there might be a new release soon. Check this one for a workaround: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/609#issuecomment-359126411

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be resolved with [CLI version 3.17.4](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v3.17.4).

Comment: yeah Thanks, I notice that, thank you for your help.